# Cannot access the hardware clock as a non-root user

Tags: arch-linux, non-root-user, clock

I try to use the hwclock but I get this output:

```
[arkadi@arkadi-linux /home/arkadi $]hwclock 
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

When I use debug I got this message:

```
[arkadi@arkadi-linux /home/arkadi $]hwclock --debug 
hwclock from util-linux 2.26.2
hwclock: cannot open /dev/rtc: Permission denied
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

I using :

```
Linux arkadi-linux 4.0.7-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 30 07:50:21 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The permissions of `/dev/rtc0` are:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root audio 254, 0 Jul  5  2015 /dev/rtc0
```

my group memberships are:

```
uid=1000(arkadi) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),10(wheel),95(storage),98(power)
```

how to fix it?

With sudo it works:

```
[arkadi@arkadi-linux / $]sudo hwclock
Sun 05 Jul 2015 11:35:31 AM IDT .339125 seconds
```

But it worked some time without sudo also.

Comment: Try `sudo hwclock ...`

Comment: with sudo it works:
[arkadi@arkadi-linux / $]sudo hwclock 
Sun 05 Jul 2015 11:35:31 AM IDT  .339125 seconds

But it worked some time without sudo also

Comment: If you say so. [Edit] your question to add more information. What are the permissions of `/dev/rtc0` (`ls -l /dev/rtc0`)? What are you group memberships (`id`)?

Comment: Those are unusual permissions for `/dev/rtc0`, especially the `audio` group, which seems completely irrelevant. On my system the permissions are `0600` and group `root`. The insecure permissions you have for it on your system are a security concern, but they might explain how come you were able to access it in the past without being root.

Comment: @Celada seems to be an Arch thing. Both my current Arch boxes have it, and I don't play around with `/dev`.

Comment: @muru I see. That's... eyebrow-raising to say the least, but I'll refrain from saying anything further since I don't know Arch.

Comment: If you just want to read the clock, it's also available with `cat /proc/driver/rtc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's standard for `/dev/rtc0` to belong to the `audio` group in Arch, you could just add yourself to the `audio` group (using `adduser`; you'll need to log out and log back in for the change to be effective). Alternatively, you could add an ACL giving yourself access to the device (look up `setfacl` to see how to do this).

Ideally you shouldn't need to access the RTC as yourself though...

Answer (score -1):

You need to be root to run `hwclock`.
Use:

```
su
```

to become root then type:

```
hwclock
```